# Grub bootloader not loading when windows boot manager is first option in boot order

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, grub, bootloader

I have windows and linux mint dual boot on a single SSD.

When I keep windows boot manager the first place in boot order, the GRUB bootloader doesn't appear at all. It directly boots me into windows.

When I put ubuntu (Linux mint) in the first place, the GRUB bootloader appears as expected.

I want to keep windows as the first preference to boot but also want the GRUB bootloader to appear as I sometimes need to boot in Linux.

Comment: That's the way it is since ever. You may, if you need it so much, edit Grub in order to boot Windows by default but you always need to use Grub. The Windows bootloader only boots Windows, there's no way around it (as k Microsoft why), end of the story.

Comment: yep it worked. post which I used for reference, if anyone needs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader